# Python-requests: Check if URL is not HTML webpage

Tags: python, python-requests

So I have a crawler that uses something like this:

```
#if ".mp3" in baseUrl[0] or ".pdf" in baseUrl[0]:
if baseUrl[0][-4] == "." and ".htm" not in baseUrl[0]:
    raise Exception
html = requests.get(baseUrl[0], timeout=3).text
```

This works pretty well. What happens is, if a file like .mp4 or .m4a gets in the crawler instead of an HTML page, then the script hangs and in linux when I try to run the script it will just print:

```
Killed
```

Is there more of an efficient way to catch these non-HTML pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send a head request and check the content type. If its text/html then only proceed

```
r = requests.head(url)
if "text/html" in r.headers["content-type"]:
    html = requests.get(url).text
else:
    print "non html page"
```

If you just want to make single request then,

```
r = requests.get(url)
if "text/html" in r.headers["content-type"]:    
    html = r.text
else:
    print "non html page"
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that head request use a lot of bandwidth or time? It should double the time it takes for each request now, right? Is there anyway to merge this into 1 web request for efficiency?

Comment: HEAD requests should be fast as the server don't return the message-body. It just returns the meta information.

Comment: Yes it can be merged into one. the requests.get(url) also return the same headers. You can check for the content type there also. Updated the answer.

Comment: That's awesome! Should I use the `in` operator instead of `==` as some sites return more info like: `'text/html; charset=utf-8'`?

Comment: yup, in should be used